# Is it possible to update 0365 contact extensions with multiple properties in one request?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Currently on the graph API v1.0 endpoint patching a contacts extensions with multiple properties is failing using the following urls:

PATCH /users/{id|userPrincipalName}/contacts/{id}/extensions/{extensionId}

Or

PATCH /users/{id|userPrincipalName}/contactfolders/{id}/contacts/{id}/extensions/{extensionId}

Previously when patching extension data you could patch multiple property values for your extensionId as follows:

```
{
 "@odata.type": "Microsoft.OutlookServices.OpenTypeExtension",
 "extensionName": "Com.Contoso.Estimate",
 "companyName": "Contoso",
 "expirationDate": "2016-07-30T11:00:00.000Z",
 "DealValue": 1010100,
 "topPicks": [
   "Employees only",
   "Add spouse or guest",
   "Add family"
  ]
}
```

Reference URL: https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/opentypeextension_update

This functionality seems to have changed since yesterday and the below error occurs:

```
{
 "error": {
  "code": "BadRequest",
  "message": "Cannot update multiple extensions in a request.",
  "innerError": {
    "request-id": "164fba2a-003f-40b6-97cd-0f139f23345d",
    "date": "2017-02-21T20:57:03"
    }
  }
}
```

Now you are required to perform multiple calls as follows:

```
{
   "@odata.type": "Microsoft.OutlookServices.OpenTypeExtension",
   "extensionName": "Com.Contoso.Estimate",
   "companyName": "Contoso"
}
…
{
   "@odata.type": "Microsoft.OutlookServices.OpenTypeExtension",
   "extensionName": "Com.Contoso.Estimate",
   "expirationDate": "2016-07-30T11:00:00.000Z"
}
…
{
   "@odata.type": "Microsoft.OutlookServices.OpenTypeExtension",
   "extensionName": "Com.Contoso.Estimate",
   "DealValue": 1010100
}
…
{
   "@odata.type": "Microsoft.OutlookServices.OpenTypeExtension",
   "extensionName": "Com.Contoso.Estimate",
   "topPicks": [
       "Employees only",
       "Add spouse or guest",
       "Add family"
   ]
}
```

Has the v1.0 endpoint changed its functionality within this context recently?

Answer (score 0):

This was a temporary service issue that impacted only Office 365 data extensions. The issue has been identified and corrected.